# метод пузырька где ошибка?

Tags: java

```
public class BubbleSorter {
    public static void sort (int[] arr)  {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length ; j++) {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                    int t = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Знаете обычно сравнивают arr[i] с arr[j]...

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в том, что при обращении к `j + 1` элементу массива `arr`, Вы выходите за его пределы.

Пусть, например, `arr.length == 10`, тогда при `j = 9` Вы попытаетесь обратиться к элементу `arr[9 + 1] = arr[10]`, однако последний элемент массива `arr` – это `arr[9]`.

Answer (score 2):

В условии второго цикла измени `for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)` на `for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++)`. Потому что при j < arr.length идет выход за пределы массива.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` возникает из-за выхода за пределы массива, у вас во втором цикле, где  на последней итерации `arr[j + 1]` будет `arr[arr.lenght]`, то есть ошибка, вышли за предел `arr`.

Измените вложенный цикл

> `for (int j = 0; j < arr.length ; j++)`

на этот

> `for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1 ; j++)`

1. Решили проблему с выходом за пределы массива, теперь на последней итерации
    `arr[j + 1]` будет `arr[arr.lenght - 1]`
2. Не делаем лишних проверок с уже отсортированными элементами(для каждого нового i, массив, который нужно отсортировать, меньше на 1)